# Webview URL redirects/changes when launch tablet

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings, yahoo-search

I'm using webview in my application and giving hardcoded URL using the code. All things are working perfectly fine, but one thing came across when I was testing it on 10.1" tablet. The URL which I have provided works fine with the phone but on tablet it redirects itself to the desktop version of the URL.

Any idea how to prevent that from happening. I'm using this URL: http://search.yahoo.com/mobile/s?submit=oneSearch&.intl=us&.lang=en&.tsrc=yahoo&.sep=fp&x=0&y=0&p=bike

I have specifically mentioned mobile in the URL, but still it is redirecting. Any idea..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eldhose M Babu and @ankitmakwana: I have used that, but I''m not sure what is missing in that. I have attached the code, please have a look and guide me:

`mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {`

```
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            mWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            mWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mWebview.requestFocus();
        }

        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                    + "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display = 'none'; "
                    + "})()");

            mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                    + "document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].style.display = 'none'; "
                    + "})()");

            mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                    + "document.getElementsByTagName('section').search_again.style.display = 'none'; "
                    + "})()");
        }
    });

    mWebview.loadUrl("http://search.yahoo.com/mobile/s?submit=oneSearch&.intl=us&.lang=en&.tsrc=yahoo&.sep=fp&x=0&y=0&p=bike");
    setContentView(mWebview);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how its worked bcz u accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle the redirecting you need to use [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

Then override the  **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method.

**"Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView. If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url. If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url."**

Comment: Hey, I have used WebViewClient as you have mentioned but it is not working. I have shared my code on the top, please check out the code and see what went wrong.

Comment: in web view client override shouldOverrideUrlLoading method and do your required code there

Comment: I have tried using that, you can check out my code here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12276223/1321290

Please what I'm missing there.

Answer (score 0):

need to use webview client

```
        WebView   web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        web.loadUrl(myurl.trim());
    web.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient  
{

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);        
        Log.i(General.TAG,Tag+"Page Loading is Started...");
        web.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pbr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }       

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String url)
    {           
    view.loadUrl(url);  
    return true;            
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);            
        Log.i(General.TAG,Tag+"Page Loading is Finished");

        web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pbr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        web.requestFocus();
    }



}
```

Comment: Hey Ankit, I have used WebViewClient, I have shared my code on the top. Do you have any idea about that. You can check out my code.